# Centering a sub view in UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I see a bunch of similar questions on SO but none that solve my problem.

I am adding a `UIView` as a subview of `UIScrollView`. The `UIView` has 3*scrollView.width and 3*scrollView.height. So I set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` accordingly. When the app is launched I want to `scrollView` window to be in the middle of the `subView`, something like this --

```
          -------------------
          |                 |
          |    ________     | 
          |    |      |     |   
          |    |      |     |
          |    -------      |
          |                 |
          -------------------
```

The inside window is supposed to be the `scrollView` and also the portion of the `UIView` the user sees, when the app launches. However what ever I can't make it happen. 
The `scrollView` is always set to origin (0,0)

I did this -

```
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leftAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.rightAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true

scrollView.center = self.view.center // view is the base view of which scrollView is a subview of. 
subView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: -1*scrollView.frame.width)
subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: -1*scrollView.frame.height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you have `UIScrollView` and `UIView` inside that and scroll with content size 3 times of view height/width and when app launches, you need the center of the scroll.

In that case, I try to close as much possible using storyboard so what I did,

1. Added `UIScrollView` with constraints

`Top` space to SuperView, `Trailing` to SuperView, `Leading` and `Bottom` to superView.

2. Added `UIView` inside `UIScrollView` with constraints.

`Top` space to SuperView, `Trailing` to SuperView, `Leading` and `Bottom` to superView with `Height and Width` Equals to `UIView (that we have on top of UIScrollView)` with multiplier 3 times.

That's all from the storyboard, now the only thing we need to set is `setContentOffset` for `UIScrollView` like this.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let contentOffsetX = (scrollView.contentSize.width/2) - (view.bounds.width/2)
        let contentOffsetY = (scrollView.contentSize.height/2) - (view.bounds.height/2)

        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: contentOffsetX, y: contentOffsetY), animated: true)
    }
```

And we are done. I hope it will help you. 
You can also find the codebase at [Github.com](https://github.com/buntylm/StackOverFlowContribution/tree/master/Scroll)

Happy Learning.

Comment: Ah thank you. I need to set the contentOffset properly on the scrollView. That is soliving my problem. Thanks a lot for taking the time to put code out on github.